# What are the making money option available if the Adsense, Affiliate Marketing not working because of country culture?

Tags: website-promotion, monetize, money

I have a Sinhala(Main language of Sri lankan) technology blog with around 15,000 page views ( around 9,000 users) per month. Even though it is not very high I believe that I should earn at least 50$ per month from that blog. But unfortunately I am making 0$.

- Google Adsense not working because of Adsense is not supported to
  Sinhala language.
- Affiliate marketing not working because of usually Sri lankan not buy
  products via online...
- I tried to get direct advertising, but even sending 10+ emails for
  reputed companies in Sri Lanka, I did not get any ad.

Is there anything can I try? Or should I shutdown this site because of no earning?

Comment: Please be aware that questions seeking [recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic for this site due to issues with spam and self-promotional answers.

Answer (score 2):

Without having any knowledge about your country, one Google search yileded the following website: https://rumblinglankan.com/1071/netadlk-google-adsense-alternative-for-sri-lankans/

This post not only lists alternatives to adsense in your native country, but also contains other suggested ways of monetizing websites to make money, as well as what appear to be other useful tips.

I cannot speak for the quality or accuracy of this website, but hopefully it will serve as a starting point for your search. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm not to knowledgable about your particular country and what networks are allowed or indeed publish in a particular language.  But to name a few which are normally quite flexible :

- https://chitika.com/
- http://www.bidvertiser.com/
- https://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/bing-partners/sign-up
- https://www.buysellads.com/ ?

Have you tried direct advertising and reaching out to local companies that have a relation with your topic ? A banner ad or two would probably achieve your desired monthly goal with little to know effort.  Direct adverts are often much more lucrative if you have an audience which is receptive to localised advertising.

There are plenty of ways to monetise a site you may just need to get creative with what's available to you.  9000 unique visitors isn't too shabby and I see no reason to shut down,  how are your competitors monetising ?